# OpenStack Cloud Instance can't get metadata

Tags: openstack

I'm actually setting up a private cloud for my company with OpenStack (Stein). 
I followed the tutorial from the official website and everything seems to work well... except getting metadata from cloud instance.

Let me explain how is set up my infrastructure :

All OpenStack are installed on KVM host (2xXeon 32 Core, 320Go RAM, 2To HDD, ...)

I set up VM like following :

- openstack-controller001 192.168.50.11
- openstack-compute001 192.168.50.41
- openstack-storage001 192.168.50.61 (for Cinder)
- db001 192.168.50.81 (DB is not hosted on the same server as the controller)
- ldap001 192.168.50.251 (not using LDAP yet, only DNS and NTP server)

When i launch new instance of Ubuntu or Debian created from cloud images, I'm not able to connect to thoses VM via SSH, my keypair is always refused (error: permission denied). After some investigations, I realised that VM is not uploading SSH private key from the host. It seems the VM is contacting metadata server by using DHCP server IP address of my virtual network instead of metadata proxy server which is the controller if i'm not mistaken ?

```
[   15.840973] cloud-init[386]: 2019-05-20 05:53:58,124 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://172.16.10.10/latest/meta-data/instance-id' failed [0/120s]: request error [HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.16.10.10', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /latest/meta-data/instance-id (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f098d1c0e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))]
```

172.16.10.10 represents the DHCP server of my Virtual Network (172.16.0.0/16, DHCP Range 172.16.10.10~172.16.20.254). I think there is something wrong with that, despite the config seems correct.

**/etc/neutron/neutron.conf (openstack-controller001)**

```
[DEFAULT]
# ...
nova_metadata_host = openstack-controller001
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**/etc/nova/nova.conf (openstack-compute001)**

```
[neutron]
# ...
service_metadata_proxy = true
metadata_proxy_shared_secret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Usually, the metadata server can be reached by 169.254.169.254 from inside the vm. I remember that I had to add that address to noproxy of my instance's image. If you need a proxy for your VMs, try to add that magic ip to noproxy and try again.

Comment: Is the metadata server running? `systemctl status openstack-neutron-metadata-agent.service`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.

Metadata server is running on openstack-controller001 :

```
[admin@openstack-controller001 ~]$ systemctl status neutron-metadata-agent
\u25cf neutron-metadata-agent.service - OpenStack Neutron Metadata Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/neutron-metadata-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since \u6708 2019-05-20 14:45:59 JST; 23h ago
 Main PID: 15329 (/usr/bin/python)
   CGroup: /system.slice/neutron-metadata-agent.service
           \u251c\u250015329 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/neutron-metadata-agent --config-...
           \u251c\u250015357 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/neutron-metadata-agent --config-...
           \u2514\u250015358 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/neutron-metadata-agent --config-...

 5\u6708 20 14:45:59 openstack-controller001.adoc.local systemd[1]: Stopped Open...
 5\u6708 20 14:45:59 openstack-controller001.adoc.local systemd[1]: Started Open...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I don't know if my VM can reach 169.254.169.254 server but from network namespace, it does

```
[admin@openstack-controller001 ~]$ openstack network list
+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   | Name          | Subnets                              |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| 838b6191-33d6-4683-958e-cee434518743 | provider      | d524b6e6-24ad-4a28-9482-b03f4bf22690 |
| c6ed4cfe-43b4-42b7-8fb5-f205a962f9f7 | adoc-net-main | 053681d8-4d5c-4ef4-8be7-f2276d43b26c |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------------------------+
[admin@openstack-controller001 ~]$ ip netns
qdhcp-838b6191-33d6-4683-958e-cee434518743 (id: 0)
qrouter-3a164855-6c8f-447c-8b0f-49e86d823488 (id: 2)
qdhcp-c6ed4cfe-43b4-42b7-8fb5-f205a962f9f7 (id: 1)

[root@openstack-controller001 admin]# ip netns exec qdhcp-c6ed4cfe-43b4-42b7-8fb5-f205a962f9f7 ping 169.254.169.254
PING 169.254.169.254 (169.254.169.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 169.254.169.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.169.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.169.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.169.254: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.169.254: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
```

Is it normal that VM is looking for local metadata server from DHCP server ?